Futter, how to have multiple working FAB's
I'm trying to implement a feature in Flutter that will allow me to create a fab that works like a quick menu of sorts. I want that when you press it, 2 other fabs appear, which then provide possible options. I managed to get the animation to work, but only the fab that is responsible for the animation works. The other FABs cannot be pressed and do not show any animation when they are tapped.
class _PageScreenState extends ConsumerState<PageScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late ShoppingList shoppingList;
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<Offset> _offsetAnimation1;
  late Animation<Offset> _offsetAnimation2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      vsync: this,
    );

    _offsetAnimation1 = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: Offset.zero,
      end: Offset(0.0, -1.5),
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    ));

    _offsetAnimation2 = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: Offset.zero,
      end: Offset(-1.0, -1.0),
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    ));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int index = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as int;

    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            SlideTransition(
              position: _offsetAnimation1,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: 'qrButton',
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {
                  // Add functionality here
                  //TODO: This Button is not Pressable
                  print("Button Pressed");
                },
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                  side: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
                ),
                child: Icon(Icons.qr_code, color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
              ),
            ),
            SlideTransition(
              position: _offsetAnimation2,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: 'addButton',
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {
                  //TODO: This Button is not Pressable
                  print("Button Pressed")
                },
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                  side: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
                ),
                child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
              ),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                if (_controller.isDismissed) {
                  _controller.forward();
                } else {
                  _controller.reverse();
                }
              },
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                side: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
              ),
              child: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Text(
                "Text",
              ),
      ),
    );
  }



see Expandable FAB here

Using offsets simply draws the secondary "floating" buttons outside the bounds of the parent widget (the widget passed to the Scaffold).
What's happening is that the initial FloatingActionButton only takes up as much size as it needs, and then the other two buttons simply say: "Hey, paint me at this offset!", but the size of the original button never changes.
Since hit testing is based on the constraints/size of the parent widget, and that size is still only as big as the parent FloatingActionButton, but the children buttons are drawing themselves outside that size, the hit testing fails.
To solve this, you would have to ensure that the parent widget is large enough to accommodate the offset positions:
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    floatingActionButton: SizedBox.expand( // <= take up all available space
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
        child: Stack(/*rest of your code*/),
      ),
    ),
    body: const Text("Text"),
  );
}

